# Make conditions in Pandas DataFrames optional (based on user input)

Tags: python, pandas

In a script that accepts user input to query several columns of a spreadsheet, I am using Pandas to combine conditions, e.g.

```
output1=f.loc[f['pers_name'].isin(user_list) & (f['event_start'].values==q_year)]
```

If there are just two conditions, I can easily use `if` and `else` to handle cases in which the user either does not enter person names or no date to retrieve all data that meet just one of the conditions.

However, I eventually need to manage six different columns. Is there a way to make the DataFrame treat conditions as optional if there is no user input for one or more without `if` and `elif` for all possible combinations?

I was hoping there was an argument I could add to each condition, but I have not found what I am looking for in the documentation yet.

Answer (score 1):

In this kind of cases, we can use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) like in this example :

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

val1 = 1
val2 = 10

condlist = [df['col1'] == val1, 
            df['col1'] == val2, 
            df['col3'] == val1]

choicelist = [df['column1'],
              df['column2'],
              df['column3']]            

df['Vals'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @tlentali 's sample, I have been able to ingest user input as variables in a condition list.

Each input can be a list of keywords separated by commas. The input is then split:

```
# separate user input if lists have been submitted
qn=q_name.split(",")
qy=q_year.split(",")
qi=q_inst.split(",") 
qt=q_title.split(",") 
qf=q_func.split(",") 
qr=q_rel.split(",")

# define possible conditions

condlist = [f['pers_name'].isin(qn), 
            f['event_start'].isin(qy),
            f['inst_name'].isin(qi), 
            f['pers_title'].isin(qt),
            f['pers_function'].isin(qf),
            f['rel_pers'].isin(qr)]

# define full range of choices

choicelist = [f['pers_name'], 
            f['event_start'],
            f['inst_name'], 
            f['pers_title'],
            f['pers_function'],
            f['rel_pers']]
```

As I want to capture all relevant cells values in the original EXCEL table (read as DataFrame `f`), I am retrieving the following output:

```
output = np.select(condlist, choicelist, default=0)
new_array=f.to_numpy()
rows=np.where(output)
print("Elements meeting required conditions:", new_array[rows])
```

The output looks like this in the console:

```
Elements meeting required conditions: 
[['Stk_00010' 9 nan ... nan nan nan]
 ['Stk_00052' 9 nan ... nan nan nan]
 ['Stk_00087' 9 nan ... nan nan nan]
 ...
 ['Stk_03161' 805 nan ... nan nan nan]
 ['Stk_05965' 804 nan ... nan nan nan]
 ['Stk_05966' 805 nan ... nan nan nan]]
Done.
```